# What are isolated zeroes? How are they related to total derivative at 'a' being an invertible linear map?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assume that $U$ is an open set in $R^n$, and $a \in U$. Let f$:U \to R^n$ be differentiable at $a$. Suppose that $Df(a)$ is an invertible linear mapping.

Please explain the implication

> $a$ is an “isolated zero” for $f-f(a)$, which means that there exists a neighborhood $U_1$ of $a$ contained in $U$ such that for every $x \in U_1$ with $f(x) = f(a)$, we have $x = a$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there is some $x_n$ with $0 < |x_n - a| < 1/n$ and $f(x) = f(a)$.

The sequence

$$
y_n := \frac{x_n - a}{|x_n - a|}
$$

is a bounded sequence in a finite dimensional space, hence has a convergent subsequence, which I will again denote by $(y_n)_n$ with $y_n \to y$.

Note that $|y| = \lim_n |y_n| = 1 \neq 0$. As $Df(a)$ is invertible, this yields $Df(a) \cdot y \neq 0$.

But

\begin{eqnarray*}
0 \neq -Df(a) \cdot y & \longleftarrow & -Df(a) \cdot y_n =- Df(a) \cdot \frac{x_n - a}{|x_n -a |} \\ & = & \frac{f(x_n) - f(a) - Df(a) \cdot (x_n - a)}{|x_n - a|} \\ & \to & 0,
\end{eqnarray*}

a contradiction.

This shows that there is some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that for each $x \in B_{1/n}(a)$ and each $x \in B_{1/n}(a)$, we can **only** have $f(x) = f(a)$ if $x = a$.

Put differently, there is some $\varepsilon = 1/n >0$, such that the point $a$ is the **only** point in $U_1 = B_\varepsilon (a)$ which fulfills $f(x) - f(a) = 0$.

Hence, $a$ is an isolated zero of the function $x \mapsto f(x) - f(a)$, because there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which this function has no **other** zeros.